# Why are my (non-offensive) Roblox messages being censored?

Tags: roblox

My friend said he was gonna quit Roblox, and I tried to reply through Roblox asking him why. I specifically said:

> What? "Why would you quit?"

which got censored with hashtags. I found this a bit odd, so I messaged some other people and those messages got censored as well. (It was just simple things like Hi, Hello, etc.) I was a bit confused (Obviously).

Why is this happening? How can I fix it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I recall a time where the Roblox filters threw a big tantrum and decided to tag every single message no matter what you said. This is what might be happening to you.

Comment: Same here. Roblox decided to censor all my "u"s in my messages.

Comment: roblox filter will forever be terrible

Answer (score 5):

Roblox complies with COPPA so has to filter out inappropriate text (both toxic language,  information regarding contact details, impersonating, dating and many many others).

The filter has different settings based on the age (13- or 13+) and other settings (like chat with friend, no chat, everyone) of your profile and the profile of whom you are discussing, but the filter is known to be overprotective and block some normal messages.

You can check the Roblox community rules here

https://en.help.roblox.com/hc/en-us/articles/203313410-Roblox-Community-Rules

and if there are certain words / texts that you think it should not be filtered then please raise this with Roblox here: https://www.roblox.com/support

Comment: Yeah #### hate ## wh## that happens ########